# Variable doesn't work inside JQuery scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll, scrolltop

my goal is to create and display variable which will record scroll position. While the scroll function seems to be working (for example i can alert a message inside it) but when I add a `scroll_pos` variable it just stops working. I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwgODLLSgwU but i don't understand what's wrong with my code. I use `<div id="'status>` to display the variable. Any suggestions?
Here's the code  https://jsfiddle.net/avxgeeah/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#text_area").scroll(function(){
        var scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        alert(scroll_pos);
    });
});
```

Comment: Just use waypoints, which does exactly this: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Comment: You code works fine.  In js fiddle use https for jquery.  See this fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jkuhns/5gb3k9vL/)

Comment: thanks @jkuhns5 it now works in jsFiddle but still doesn't make any difference on my local hosting

Comment: try adding 

'console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);'

in a script tag on your page to see if jquery is actually loading.  it should return the version number if it is.

Answer (score 0):

it works here https://jsfiddle.net/j5vg0fsj/

```
$("#target").scroll(function(){
    var scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    alert(scroll_pos);
});
```

I know that chrome will offer to disable alerts if they are firing too frequently. Perhaps you okayed that?